# Raspberry pi opencv configuration issue

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, raspberry-pi

I have recently installed opencv 2.4.8 on my raspberry pi.When i check the version with

```
pkg-config --modversion opencv
2.4.8
```

But in my python code when i import cv2 i am getting the error as no module named cv2.I have checked my usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages and it is empty. How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Find cv2.so file (probably found at " ~/opencv-2.4.9/release"), or search it using

```
find / -name "cv2.so"
```

Copy this to usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages and you should be able to import cv2. If not, append the below two lines to your code:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
```